# Background just stops after adding elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my website. I add a variable amount of elements to a page based on a JSON file. If there are too many, the background color just stops.
However, it seems like the problem only occurs in Firefox and Edge. It looks fine on Chrome.

This is the general CSS code for my layout:

```
body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    display: grid;                              
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 20px;               
    grid-template-columns: 13% 87%;         
    height: 100vh;                              
    grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar content"
    "footer footer";
}

main{
    background-color:#D0CABF;
    grid-area: content;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 30% 1fr 20%;    
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-areas:
    "top"
    "mid"
    "bottom";
 }
```

This is the JS code:

```
$.getJSON('/data/risks.json', function(data) {
var html = '';
$.each(data.risk, function(key, value){
    html += '<div class="cardS">';
    html += '<br><p><b>'+value.name+'</b><br><br>'+value.description+'<br><p class="hiddenID">'+value.id+'</p></p>';
    html += '</div>';
 });
$('#jsondata').html(html);
});
```

I've tried to set the position of the body to "fixed" but it seems like this prevents scrolling. I'm not sure how to solve this problem...

Here is a screenshot:
[image: ]]

Thanks!

Comment: What about the JavaScript

Comment: Added the JavaScript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the block inside the **main** are floated and may be there is not **clearfix CSS** for it OR clear CSS to clear the floated blocks.

You may use

```
.clear{clear: both; display: block;}
```

Comment: Thanks! clearfix was indeed the solution for my problem.